# How do I join a string and an int in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, procedure, timescaledb

I have a procedure with an int parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_retention_policy(id int, days int)
    language plpgsql
AS
$$
    BEGIN
        PERFORM add_retention_policy(('schema_' + id + '.my_hypertable'), days * INTERVAL '1 day', true);
    END
$$;
```

The syntax for the `add_retention_policy` function is `add_retention_policy('hypertable', INTERVAL 'x days', true)`. I want to prefix the hypertable with the schema which is always 'schema_' and then followed by the id parameter, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to rewrite the INTERVAL part in your function call as `days * INTERVAL '1 day'`.

Instead of concatenating strings, you multiply the '1 day' interval by the `days` param.

EDIT: for the `id` part, you can just use the `||` operator, which is the string concatenation operator in Postgres, instead of `+`. You shouldn't even need to explicitly cast `id` to `character varying`

Comment: Aah, why did I not think of that. Okay that works, but what if I have to pass schema also. I've updated the OP. The multiply logic would not work in that case, how do I solve that? Note that the id parameter is an int, which i have to concat with a string...

Comment: Updated my answer; as a side note, || will not work for the days part, as it would clash with INTERVAL syntax, multiplying is still the way to go

Comment: Thank you very much, so I run it like this: `PERFORM add_retention_policy(('schema_' || '.my_hypertable'), days * INTERVAL '1 day', true);`. It gives the following error: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying * interval
LINE 1: ...icy(('schema_' || '.my_hypertable'), days * INTERVAL...`

Comment: It points to the multiply operator...

Comment: are you sure `days` is declared as an int parameter? Please edit your question with the full function definition and a sample call you're doing

Comment: It was pointing to a wrong parameter I used to test with, and it was not an int. Works like charm, thank you very much sir!!!